# Still stuck at updating nested object values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

###### hi everyone (again), still stuck on this...

i got a nested object, (for the sake of simplicity, i've updated the object to be much less complicated) here is what it looks like:

```
export const customerDraft = {
  _id: "6368dab51482da28ba792712",
  firstName: "Jane",
  lastName: "Doe",
  metadata: {
    birthDate: "25.07.1999",
    gender: "Female",
    status: "Adult",
  },
};
```

the problem to be solved is as follows:

- i have to display all the keys of the object as inputs so the user can update it. (which was fairly easy, i did it using recursion) here is what it looks like:

```
const Inputs = ({ data }) => {
  // const [updatedCustomerDraft, setUpdatedCustomerDraft] = useState({});

  return (
    <form style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap", gap: "2em" }}>
      {Object.keys(data).map((key, i) => {
        if (data[key] !== null && typeof data[key] === "object") {
          return <Inputs key={i} data={data[key]} />;
        }
        return (
          <FormControl key={i}>
            <InputLabel>{key}</InputLabel>
            <Input
              defaultValue={data[key]}
              onInput={(e) => {
                const { value } = e.target;

                handleChange(key, value, data);
              }}
            />
          </FormControl>
        );
      })}
    </form>
  );
};
```

and also the picture: [image]

### Now the tricky part:

- whenever user types something in that input, the object should be dynamically updated, for example if user types 'Ann', in  firstName, firstname value should be equal to 'Ann'. and if the user types for example 'non-binary' in gender key, its value should also be updated.

i want to create deep copy of the initial object, update it and then return the updated object.
this is currently where i'm at:

i successfully made a deep copy.

```
const deepCopy = (data) => {
  const newData = {};
  Object.keys(data).forEach((key, i) => {
    if (data[key] !== null && typeof data[key] === "object") {
      deepCopy(data[key]);
    }
    newData[key] = data[key];
  });
  return newData;
};
```

now that i've got duplicate object, i can make changes to it without changing the original object. now my goal is to change these values corresponding to inputs user types.

the approach i chose is as follows:

```
const copiedData = deepCopy(customerDraft);

const handleChange = (key, value, data) => {
  Object.keys(data).map((i) => {
    if (typeof data[i] === "object" && data[i] !== null) {
      handleChange(key, value, data[key]);
    } // this condition checks if the value of a key is an object or not, then if it is, calls the function recursively, to iterate over the nested object keys.

   // here i want to check that if the key equals the current input item, and if it is, i want to set it to the e.target.value

  });
};
```

i don't know if it is the best **solution**, or if it even is a **solution**, but that's the best i came up with.

**in case what i'm trying to solve is not clear:
see the attached picture above,
what i need is that if the user types in 'Minor' in 'status' field, the new object should look like this:**

```
export const customerDraft = {
  _id: "6368dab51482da28ba792712",
  firstName: "Jane",
  lastName: "Doe",
  metadata: {
    birthDate: "25.07.1999",
    gender: "Female",
    status: "Minor", // instead of adult
  },
};
```

##### Any feedback at all with a good explanation would be much appreciated!!

##### thanks!

Comment: typeof data[i] === "object" not sufficient to check object type data. Since typeof([]) is also 'object'. Instead use if(typeof data[i] === "object" && !Array.isArray(data[i]))

Comment: yes i know that, my object doesn't have any arrays, so it should work fine, thanks for useful info tho, but that's not what i need. 

I need to create a copy of my initial object and then i need to update its values based on the values typed by the user.

for example if user types in 'Minor' in 'status' input field. the object should look like this:
```
export const customerDraft = {
  _id: "6368dab51482da28ba792712",
  firstName: "Jane",
  lastName: "Doe",
  metadata: {
    birthDate: "25.07.1999",
    gender: "Female",
    status: "Minor",
  },
};

```

Comment: About the deep copy, instead of doing a recursion which works perfectly fine, did you try to do JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objectToDeeplyCopy)) ?

Comment: About the tricky part, during your recursion, I would create a Map which has properties as key and the "path" as value. Entries would look like [['lastName', ''], ['metadata', ''], ['birthDate', 'metadata']]

So when you have to update birthDate, you get the 'path' of your property to update it in your copy

Comment: Is customerDraft and data which has been used in form referring to same variable ?.
please add working example for best solution.

Comment: @HediZitouni well, i have not, the problem is not deep copy, the problem is that i can not change the values of the copied object, based on what the user typed in. thanks for the suggestion and your time

Comment: @OmprakashSharma yes it is, data is just a prop which <Inputs /> component takes in, and I'm passing customerDraft to my inputs component, you can tell that  from the picture i attached, there are input fields generated according to the customerDraft object

Comment: @HediZitouni 'path' actually is a good idea, but i cant seem to figure out how to write that code...

Comment: IMO you're overcomplicating it. You don't need a deep copy, you can use the spread operator to update a single property. Please provide us a working example which we can edit. Codepen is something you can try or even Stack Overflow's own editor.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh will do sir, thanks, i'll update the post with the link to the codepen

Comment: @DhavalJardosh https://codepen.io/ikkakoo/pen/rNKGbyV?editors=1111 <<< here is the codepan example, there are fields rendered recursively according to the object, 

what i want to do and cant seem to figure it out is to write a logic in handleChange function to update the fields of the object, so if the user types in something the value of the object should be also updated.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh if you use spread operator, you will keep the reference of a nested object, which is not what a deep copy should do

Comment: Yes i dont want to change initial object, i want to update the copied one, and then send it to backend to update the object in database, but that can wait, i just need to inplement the functionality, doesnt matter on which obj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit complex but it is working
Let me just tell you that I am pretty sure there are easier approaches.

Here is the simplest example that you can reproduce on your project:

```
// returns a map with properties as key and path as values
function createMapPath(obj, path, mapPath) {
    for (let [k,v] of Object.entries(obj)){
    const currentPath = `${path}${path ? '.' : ''}${k}`
    if (typeof v === "object") {createMapPath(v, currentPath, mapPath)}
    else {mapPath.set(k,path)}
    
  }
  return mapPath
}

// get property of obj, based on path
function getParentProp(obj, path) {
    const s = path.split('.')
  const prop = s.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    return acc[curr]
  }, obj)
  return prop
}

// Change data[key] to value
function handleChange(key, value, data) {
    const parent = getParentProp(data, globalMapPath.get(key))
    parent[key] = value
}

const example = {foo: {b: 1, bar: {baz: 0}}}

// Generate the mapPath of 'example'
const globalMapPath = createMapPath(example, '', new Map())


console.log('baz before change', example.foo.bar.baz)
handleChange('baz', 10, example)
console.log('baz after change', example.foo.bar.baz)
```

Comment: could you explain how does this work so that i understand? if you have time that is... thanks btw

Comment: createMapPath will create by recursion a map with non-object properties as keys and path as value  
With the example: [['b', 'foo'], ['baz', 'foo.bar']]  

getParentProp will get a property of an object, based on a path as string. Normally you can't do  `example['foo.baz'], so getParentProp(example, 'foo.bar') will return {baz:0}  

To modify the property of an object, you have to generate the mapPath, `const globalMapPath = createMapPath(example, '', new Map())`  

Now `handleChange('baz', 10, example)` gives to the property baz of 'example' the value 10